# Why sidekiq returned error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying to use sidekiq in my app, but when I write this simple worker

```
class ParseWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(instance)
    instance.spideys << Spidey.create
  end
end
```

and I use this worker here

```
  def create
    @user_link = UserLink.new(user_link_params)
    if @user_link.save
      binding.pry
      ParseWorker.perform_async(@user_link)
      redirect_to results_user_links_path
    end
  end
```

was returned the error

```
2015-04-09T13:14:56.757Z 11644 TID-ay1nc ERROR: Actor crashed!
NoMethodError: undefined method `spideys' for "#<UserLink:0x007f65f00d99b0>":String
    /home/weare138/simple-parser/app/workers/parse_worker.rb:7:in `perform'
```

but why? @user_link is not a string

how fix?

**upd**

```
  def perform(id)
    user_link = UserLink.find(id)
    user_link.spideys << Spidey.create
  end
```

error

```
2015-04-09T14:15:21.889Z 11644 TID-ay1nc ERROR: Actor crashed!
NoMethodError: undefined method `spideys' for 39:Fixnum
```

**upd2**

```
class ParseWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  require 'open-uri'

  def perform(id)
    user_link = UserLink.find(id)
    user_link.spideys << Spidey.create
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq uses Redis, so when you pass to the worker an object, it serializes it to JSON.

From the Sidekiq documentation:

> This means the arguments to your worker must be simple JSON datatypes
>   (numbers, strings, boolean, array, hash). Complex Ruby objects (e.g.
>   Date, Time, ActiveRecord instances) will not serialize properly.

Instead you should do

```
def create
  ...
  ParseWorker.perform_async(@user_link.id)
end


def perform(id)
  UserLink.find(id).spideys << Spidey.create
end
```

Comment: hmm, now return new error `NoMethodError: undefined method spideys for 39:Fixnum`

Comment: you are not doing this then `UserLink.find(id).spideys`

Comment: please include the whole ParseWorker file

Comment: hmm, I use guard-sidekiq gem, he must reload every worker.But well, I will restart, thank you